# Failed to debug grpc channelz with web tool

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

In this doc [A short introduction to Channelz](https://grpc.io/blog/a-short-introduction-to-channelz/), there is a web tool called [grpc-zpages](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-experiments/tree/master/gdebug) conveniently serve channelz data through a web page.

However, we cannot find any `TopChannels` data from this web tool. Does someone meet the same issue?

To make this web tool run, there are some changes to the codes

1. Add the following codes to `http_filters` of `zprox.sh`

```
                function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                  filter_name = "ENVOY"
                  response_handle:headers():add("my_Filter", filter_name)
                end
```

to solve the error `envoy_on_response() function not found. lua filter will not hook responses`

2. Comment `network_mode: 'host'` of `start_docker.sh` to solve the error `docker.errors.InvalidArgument: "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings`
3. Replace `manual.GenerateAndRegisterManualResolver()` with

```
    r := manual.NewBuilderWithScheme("whatever")
    r.InitialState(resolver.State{Addresses: []resolver.Address{{Addr: ":10001"}, {Addr: ":10002"}, {Addr: ":10003"}}})

    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(r.Scheme()+":///test.server",
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithResolvers(r),
        grpc.WithDefaultServiceConfig(`{"loadBalancingPolicy":"round_robin"}`),
    )
```

under `grpc 1.37.1`

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you had added channelz service and reflection service to the server. If your service is a client, you need to make the client has a grpc server also. After call server and the channel is connected, the related data could be fetched.

The grpc-zpages is not maintain anymore, and it is hard to use. I suggest to use [channelzcli](https://github.com/kazegusuri/channelzcli) replace.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble using the web tool and ended up using grpcurl.
One thing that took me a while to realize is that **in order to activate channelz on your grpc client you need to run a grpc server and enable channelz on your client service alongside your grpc client**

> Some grpcurl useful commands for Channelz:
>
> - Query for the Channelz service API, to see all available methods:
>   grpcurl -plaintext -msg-template localhost:50052 describe grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz
> - Query method template to understand what parameters it requires:
>   grpcurl -plaintext -msg-template localhost:50052 describe .grpc.channelz.v1.GetSocketReques
>
> ---
>
> Client commands examples (make sure to use the client port):
>
> - grpcurl -plaintext localhost:50052 grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz/GetTopChannels
> - grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"subchannel_id":"14"}' localhost:50052 grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz/GetSubchannel
> - grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"socket_id":"34"}' localhost:50052 grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz/GetSocket
>
> Server commands (make sure to use the server port):
>
> - grpcurl -plaintext localhost:50051 grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz/GetServers
> - grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"server_id":"2"}' localhost:50051 grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz/GetServerSockets
> - grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"socket_id":"21"}' localhost:50051 grpc.channelz.v1.Channelz/GetSocket